# The meaning of the "at the of"

Tags: meaning, phrases, syntax

In the following article by The Telegraph:
https://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/2387900/New-man-at-the-of-IMG.html
I stumbled upon the following phrase (in the title of the article):

**"New man at the of IMG"**

What does this phrase mean?
Is this even correct English? (Doesn't look like one to me :q )
Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it is a mistake too. Maybe they left out a word & meant to say, "at the helm of...", or something like that.

Comment: And they didn't correct it since 2004? That would be weird. I lean towards a mistake as well, but it doesn't hurt to ask, just in case this were actually correct English with some obscure syntax rule in use :q

Comment: Newspapers and their online analogues can't even afford enough copyeditors to review articles before they're published, much less afterwards, when the articles are mostly of no further commercial value to the publisher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is definitely a mistake that was missed by a sub editor.

As Lorel C says, the author or editors probably made a mistake in the course of changing the title. Authors of newspaper articles generally provide a 'suggestion' for the title of the piece when they submit it, but this is nearly always changed by the sub editor before publication. In this case, a mistake was introduced.